# "Sign in with Apple" WebBridge implementation with Gigya Android Sdk

Tags: android, gigya, apple-sign-in, apple-id, sign-in-with-apple

After implementing "Sign in with Apple" successfully for iOS & web, I tried the out-of-the-box Android implementation with [Gigya Android SDK v4](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Android+SDK+v4) (using the [WebBridge implementation](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Android+SDK+v4#AndroidSDKv4-UsingtheGigyaWebBridgeexplicitly.))

It's working fine, but the flow has a **very poor UX**: when tapping the Apple button in the Webview, the user is redirected **outside of my app, in the main browser**.

=> How could I keep the user inside my WebView during the whole "Sign in with Apple" flow?

Comment: How did you configure it for web ? I wasn't able to download ` apple-developer-domain-association.txt `, simply there is no option to download.

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro hosting `apple-developer-domain-association.txt` is a deprecated requirement from Apple, they stopped asking for that in March I believe

You will only need to add your domain + email address to send email to the private relay but this is it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Android SDK v4 will always direct you to your browser when using Social SDKs (except Facebook, Google, Line, WeChat as they have their own implementation guide).
There is currently no way around it.
The only way to kind of go around it is to handle the Apple sign in yourself (inside your app code) and then use the "accounts.notifySocialLogin" endpoint to continue your login flow.